# Translucent theme resulting in black background

Tags: android, android-theme

I have created a transparent activity with following style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

But I am getting black background when I open bottomsheet in that activity. Why I am getting this issue